# How to add emailed comments in image upload php form

Tags: php, image, forms, email

I am currently building a php upload page which allows the user to upload 3 images and also upload details. I have managed to get the image upload working I think, but could somebody show me how to add 5 more form sections for price, colour, size, age & description that could be emailed to me with the images when they upload to their folder on my server? Thank you my coding so far is below.

```
<?php

// filename: upload.form.php

// first let's set some variables

// make a note of the current working directory relative to root.
$directory_self = str_replace(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

// make a note of the location of the upload handler
$uploadHandler = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $directory_self . 'multiple.upload.processor.php';

// set a max file size for the html upload form
$max_file_size = 30000; // size in bytes

// now echo the html page
?>


<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">

    <title>Upload form</title>

</head>

<body id="body">

<form id="Upload" action="<?php echo $uploadHandler ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

    <h1>
        Sell-A-Car
    </h1>

    <p>
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo $max_file_size ?>">
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="file1">Item Image 1:</label>
        <input id="file1" type="file" name="file[]">
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="file2">Item image 2:</label>
         <input id="file2" type="file" name="file[]">
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="file3">Item image 3:</label>
        <input id="file3" type="file" name="file[]">
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="submit">Press to...</label>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="SELL IT!">
    </p>

</form>


</body>

</html>
```

second php file is

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 100000) . " kB<br>";
echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have the correct `enctype` on the form, you simply need to add the required text or whatever else inputs to your form. For example:

```
    <input type="text" name="myTextField"/>
```

And then in your PHP you could access it like this:

```
    $myTextFieldValue = $_POST['myTextField'];
```

Comment: Hi Tim, sorry there was no first example :)

Comment: Ah right yes, thanks @Mack for adding the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to attach the images, I would suggest taking a look at [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/). It has built in attachment functionality. So on your second page your code would look something like:

```
    include("class.phpmailer.php");
    include("class.smtp.php");

    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'yourmailserver';
    $mail->Username = 'user';
    $mail->Password = 'pw';
    $mail->Timeout = 60;

    $mail->From = 'no-reply@yourdomain.com';

    $mail->AddAddress($data['email']);  

    foreach($_FILES["file"] as $f){
        $mail->AddAttachment($f['tmp_name']);
    }

    $mail->Subject = "Subject";
    $mail->Body = "Price" . $_POST['price']"\r\n";
    $mail->Body .= "Color" . $_POST['color']"\r\n";
        $mail->Body .= "Size" . $_POST['size']"\r\n";


   if(!$mail->Send()) {  
        $mail->SMTPDebug = true;
        $mail->Debugoutput = 'echo';
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        exit;
    }
```

And make sure you add the parameters in your fist page html something like:

```
<p>
        <label for="color">Color:</label>
        <input id="color" type="text" name="color">
    </p>
```